# Can anyone help me edit my code to pull specific file names instead of all the files in the folder like it currently does

Tags: python, file, directory, subdirectory

Just trying to figure out what I am missing. I need this code to pull files with a specific name into a specific folder, this currently pulls all files within the folder. file name example I'm attempting to pull is 'USA_2017-10-14_rci_box1.tif' and I would like to select it using the number of the day within the file name, but if not the whole file name would be fine as well.

```
#pulls everything from the folder, but not a specific file name string

def movefiles(folder, ctr, stop):
    print('moving')
    for i in range(0, stop):
        day_delta = ctr.date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
        src_fldr = r'path/source/folder'  # Replace 'path/source/folder' with the actual source folder path
        src_items = os.listdir(src_fldr)

        for rci in src_items:
            rci_segments = rci.split('_')
            output_folder = os.path.join(folder, rci_segments[0])

            if ctr.country in rci and str(rci_segments[1]) == str(day_delta):
                print(rci)
            local_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, 'del{}'.format(rci))

            try:
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(src_fldr, rci), local_filename)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error: {str(e)}')

            out_rast = os.path.join(folder, r'{}\{}'.format(rci_segments[0], rci))

            ctr.rasters.append([local_filename, out_rast])
            if str(rci_segments[1]) == str(ctr.date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
                ctr.mosaic.append(out_rast)
    print('-------------')
    return
```

I tried a for file in files loop, but I don't think I wrote it correctly because it still pulled all of the files in the folder. No error messages received, but it did not run how i expected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these errors cause your problem：
When matching file names, you attempted to use 'str (rci_segments [1])==str (day_delta)' for comparison. This compares the file name fragment with the date object, rather than the date string.And you execute 'shutil. copy' and 'ctr. masters. append' every iteration, not just when a matching file name is found.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing! I'm still fairly new to python, but how would i get it to compare to the date string instead?

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out my issue thanks to your help even though I executed shutil.copy every iteration, I had to change the comparison like you mentioned. Thank you again!